# How to load assets from .pug template with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, sass, html-webpack-plugin, pug-loader

I am going through a CSS course and have got tired of typing out similar HTML structures by hand, so I hooked up pug templates and webpack-dev-server to serve it.

**NOTE:** my entry point is `.scss` file not `.js`

I have two issues:

a) only assets from css get loaded to build folder, but images and svg's that are referenced in `src` attributes in `.pug` template are left out.

b) browser reloading doesn't work in `webpack-dev-server`

My `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './sass/main.scss',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'css/style.css',
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: ['pug-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
            },
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          // {
          //   loader: 'file-loader',
          //   options: {
          //     name: 'img/[name].[ext]',
          //   }
          // },
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              publicPath: "../",
              name: 'img/[name].[ext]',
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './test.pug',
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: 'img/favicon.png',
      cache: false,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/style.css'),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    compress: true,
    open: 'firefox',
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this topic is of no interest to anybody, but I've found the solution and here it is:

a) in order to trigger webpack to include your assets from `.pug` template into dependency graph require them:

```
img(
    alt="Your image"
    src=require("./img/image.jpg")
)
```

However you can not do the same with SVG's if you access all of them from a single sprite. Because:

```
svg
   use(xlink:href=require("./img/sprite.svg#icon"))
```

will throw and exception saying that it couldn't find a file by that name.

So what I did was requiring the whole sprite in the beginning of the template `require("./img/sprite.svg")`
and then just specified icons in usual way:

```
svg
   use(xlink:href="./img/sprite.svg#icon")
```

b) As for the reloading issue, it wasn't that easy. I played around with `MiniCssExtractPlugin` options but still couldn't get it to reload. So I ended up taking ideas from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/helpse/a3419706c1d937470fedf31800b7f625) and [this repo](https://github.com/impulse/webpack4-pug-sass-example). Had to change the structure of my project little and create `index.js` as an entry point though.